# How can I pass the pathnames in a file as arguments to a shell script?

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a file `~/filelist`, where each line is a file's pathname, which  may contain whitespaces:

```
/path/to/my file1
/another path/to/my file2
```

I have a script which can accept filenames as arguments:

```
myscript.sh "/path/to/my file1"  "/another path/to/my file2"
```

The following commands will not work however

```
myscript.sh $(cat ~/filelist)
```

and

```
arr=($(cat ~/filelist))
myscript.sh "${arr[@]}"
```

How can I make the script work with `~/filelist`? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual word-splitting reasons described in

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373)
- [Greg's Wiki WordSplitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)

For that particular case on Bash, using `mapfile` and the array it provides is cleanest, since you don't need to touch word splitting directly:

```
$ mapfile -t paths < filelist
$ myscript.sh "${paths[@]}"
```

Or if you want to, directly with word-splitting:

```
$ set -o noglob     # disable globbing, same as 'set -f'
$ IFS=$'\n'         # split only on newlines
$ myscript $(cat filelist)
```

Comment: Thanks. In the script there is `ls -l "${@}"`, why does it report error `ls: cannot access '"/path/to/my file1"': No such file or directory` and  `ls: cannot access '"/another path/to/my file2"': No such file or directory`?

Comment: @Tim, you have the literal quotes there, in the data? You don't need them, and they'd only be useful if you `eval` the command containing the filenames.

Comment: Thanks. In `filelist`, I double quoted the pathnames which contain whitespaces